# Streaming the microphone in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, streaming

I can send files, messages and even video but no microphone streamming code seen to work as should.

files, messages and video have some kind of minimal structure that I can send and rebuild in the other side, but audio seems to have no structure simple to work on.

At this point already tried to use [**this**](http://www.stefanpopp.de/capture-iphone-microphone/) project as base and send the AudioBuffer whith MCSession, but the code just crash when i tried to modify the buffer on the receive side.

I also tried to modify [**this**](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity) stream program to uses the microphone but the stream of files seems different then the excepted for real-time audio input.

Have someone tried something like streaming real-time microphone data to another iOS device? or have any advice or clue that i can work on?

thank you in advance!